# index out of bounds when multiplying a double

Tags: java, android, android-intent, indexoutofboundsexception

First time posting.  Thanks for the help in advance.

I have two activities.  First activity reads in 3 numbers from the user via edittext fields whose inputType is "numberDecimal".  It bundles these and sends them to the second activity via intent.

The second activity reads in the 3 numbers.  It then needs to multiply them by some constants.  That's where the problem comes in.  If the result of the multiplication is too large (say, greater than a couple hundred...not constant threshold...not close to what a double should be able to hold) then it throws an indexoutofboundsexception.

```
//@SuppressWarnings ("serial)")
public class CreationActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.creation);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelTitle);
    TextView txtArtist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelArtist);
    TextView txtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelTitle);

    try {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        double Hours;
        double Minutes;
        double Seconds;

        if (extras!=null){
            double timerTime[] = extras.getDoubleArray("Time");
            Hours = timerTime[0];
            Minutes = timerTime[1];
            Seconds = timerTime[2];
                            //next line is where the error happens:
            double desired_time = timerTime[0] * 5000;
                            //do some stuff
        }else{
            txtTitle.setText("No data");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
    }
}
}
```

And the LogCat is:

```
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.decker.timer/com.decker.timer.CreationActivity}:    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at com.decker.timer.CreationActivity.onCreate(CreationActivity.java:172)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-27 21:58:41.736: E/AndroidRuntime(31560):    ... 11 more
07-27 21:58:49.260: D/TimerActivity(31583): onClicked
```

Comment: Can you indicate which line in the code you posted corresponds to line 172 in the original source, as per `at com.decker.timer.CreationActivity.onCreate(CreationActivity.java:172)`?

Comment: hmmm...line 172 falls into the //do some other stuff category...let me look into that a bit more.  It makes no sense that the multiplication wouldn't work...

Comment: i don't see the ArrayList in the code you posted, please post the code around line 172 from your CreationActivity.

Comment: or better yet, go to the condition of line 172 and put < instead of <= or ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to access the 5th (item at position 4) item in an array of length four.

Comment: agreed, but not sure why.  desired_time is a double, not an array.  multiplication should be simple.  I've checked timerTime[] has 3 elements and all have the correct value...i.e. they are being bundled and passed correctly.

Comment: @sdecker The error is coming from somewhere else, this is not the right line. Multiplication has nothing to do with it. You may want to rebuild everything from scratch to re-synchronize line numbers in the source with the most recent compiled code.

Comment: Found it.  It was something to do with a different array.  That array had only 4 elements and I was trying to access a 5th one (as SandersKY said).  That statement, however, was inside a while loop whose conditions were dependent on the value of desired_time as well as a few other things.  Thus, if desired_time were smaller values it never enter the while loop and no error resulted.  However, if desired_time were such that the while loop's conditions were met, then the 5th element of the array was attempted and error resulted.